# PHP causing server error 500

Tags: php, nginx, apache2

Does anyone have a clue what it is about this bit of php code that would cause an apache2 webserver with nginx to throw a server error 500?

```
function cycleColsDbl() {
    static $cols = ['transparent;', '#efefef;'], $i = 0;
    $selectCol = ($i++/2 % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
    return $cols['$selectCol'];
}
```

The server suexec.log spat out a rather nonsensical claim:

```
[2016-04-17 08:34:34]: uid: (10003/usr) gid: (1003/1003) cmd: cgi_wrapper
```

And error.log says nothing at all about this.

The 500 is thrown on page load so the function never actually gets called.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `$cols['$selectCol'];` will look for a key `$selectCol`, not `0` or `1`. It would look for `0` or `1` if you didn't make it literal, i.e. remove the single quotes.

Also, `static $cols = ['transparent;', '#efefef;']` is not correct syntax to create an array in PHP.

```
function cycleColsDbl() {
    static $cols = array('transparent;', '#efefef;'), $i = 0;
    $selectCol = ($i++/2 % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
    return $cols[$selectCol];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the array issue that was throwing the 500 on the server. Now works correctly. :)